# Two WCF services expose same entity as two different classes

Tags: wcf, datacontract

Our WCF service solution consists of three projects:

1. Business Logic (`AddressChangeBL` & `AddressBL`)
2. Entities (POCOs) (`Address`)
3. Service (`AddressChangeService` & `AddressService`)

Now, the service project has two separate services, each exposing the same entity. When I reference the service in an ASP.Net application, the same entity is referenced via two different namespaces (`AddressChangeService.Address` & `AddressService.Address`)

In my code, I need to send an `Address` entity to *both* services. First to the `AddressService.IsValid` method, then to the `AddressChangeService.UpdateAddress` method.

Even though, in the service, the `Address` entities are the same class, in the ASP.Net application they are two different classes.

How do I go about resolving this issue?

I know of a couple of workarounds, but none are good for us:

1. Add a reference to the entities directly using the `Entities` assembly, not via the service. This is not an acceptable solution for us, as our requirements demand that we use the entities created by the WSDL.
2. Move the `IsValid()` method from the `AddressService` to the `AddressChangeService`. This is not acceptable either as it violates our desired separation of concerns.

I would like a "solution" rather than a "workaround, if possible.

Comment: If these are 2 different WCF services, the Address will be defined in each one separately when you consume them, then they are not the same class. they just look the same.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the classes ARE different. They may have the same signature, but they are different (C# isn't duck typed).

The reason is that when you "referenced" the service you used "Add Service Reference". What this does is it generates a new set of classes to work with the service. Since you added two services, two sets of classes were generated.

The solution is to use the option "Use Existing Types" (or something to that effect) when adding the Service Reference.

However I disagree with the statement of "Separation of Concern". I would have `AddressChangeService` inherit `AddressService`.

Comment: Like I stated in my question, referencing the Entity dll in **not** an option for us. Interesting point about the inheritance though.